# Anki - highlight/bold target word in example sentences

Tags: javascript, anki

In Anki I have a field with the target word {{hanzi}} and a field with some example sentences {{sentch}}. All example sentences contains the target word. What I would like to do is bold the target word in each example sentence. I got it working with the following script but it only bolds out the target word in the first sentence instead of all sentences. Could someone take a look?

```js
<span id="sentch"> {{sentch}} </span>

<script>

var hanzi = '{{hanzi}}';
var sentch = document.getElementById("sentch").innerHTML;
document.getElementById("sentch").innerHTML = sentch 
.replace (hanzi, "<b>" + hanzi + "</b>");

</script>
```

[example sentences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BoM7h.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`replace` by default only replaces the first occurrence if passed a string, and `replaceAll` may not be supported in the version of javascript used by anki

Try this instead

```
.replace(new RegExp(hanzi, 'g'), "<b>" + hanzi + "</b>");
```

Using regex and the /g flag will have it search the entire string for replacements.

Comment: You are my hero! Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem! Please remember to upvote and accept my answer if it solved your issue so others can find a solution more easily :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace `.replace("this", "that")` with `.replaceAll("this", "that")`

Comment: I have tried that already but that doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: Are you sure everything you want to replace is in the `#sentch` element?

What does your card template look like?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/c2aa906520b75d20414a10392a91a695 
and
https://gyazo.com/732730f1bfb38e101192a05cf5e78cbc

Comment: These are the fields, what's the HTML template like?
You can see that by going to your Deck -> Browse -> Cards

Comment: Solved! Thanks anyway :)